# Suppose $f,g$ have the following property: if $0 < |x-2| < sin^2(\frac{\epsilon^2}{9}) + \epsilon$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> Suppose $f,g$ have the following property:
>
> 1. ) if $\\0 < |x-2| < \sin^2(\frac{\epsilon^2}{9}) + \epsilon  \implies |f(x) - 2| <\epsilon$
> 2. ) if $\\0 < |x-2| < \epsilon^2  \implies |g(x) - 4| <\epsilon$
>
> for $ \epsilon > 0$, find a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$: $$|f(x)g(x) - 8| < \epsilon$$

Question/ Issue:

I know that I  have to somehow simplify my last expression to find a proper $\delta$. I also know that if I can find a way to simplify my last expression into a form such as $$|f(x)-2||g(x)-4|$$ then I would be able to use the assumptions given.

After struggling with it I looked at the solution which gave:

We need $$|f(x)-2| < \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|4| + 1)})$$ and $$|g(x) - 4| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(|2| + 1)}$$

which implies:

$$\min(\sin^2(\frac{[\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{10})]^2}{9}) + \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{10}), [\min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{6}]^2) = \delta$$

which you can see is quite tedious. So my question is how did they find thes $\delta$ and why did the assumption on the $\epsilon$ change to the complicated choice shown?

Comment: Could use a bit of cleaning.

Comment: my TeX is kinda shakey....

Comment: you can also use \left( and \right) to get the right height of parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Cut away the insignificant $O(ϵ^4)$ term, with assumption 1.) it is also true that if $|x-2|<ϵ$ then $|f(x)-2|<ϵ$.

Transform the second by replacing $ϵ$ with its square root, if $|x-2|<ϵ$ then $|g(x)-4|<\sqrtϵ$

Replace in all of the above $ϵ$ with $δ$, assume $δ\le 1$ and $|x-2|<δ$.

Then, as usual by inserting mixed terms,
$$
|f(x)g(x)-8|\le|f(x)-2|·|g(x)|+2·|g(x)-4|
< δ·(4+\sqrt{δ})+2\sqrtδ\le 7\sqrtδ,
$$
as also $\sqrtδ\le 1$.
To get this upper bound smaller than the given $ϵ$, chose $$δ=\min\Bigl(1,\frac{ϵ^2}{49}\Bigr)$$ to satisfy both of the conditions on $δ$. This might be a much stricter bound, but it also looks much more simple.

Comment: one question:  1) why is it also true that $|x-2| <\epsilon$ then $|f(x)-2|<\epsilon$? If I were to ignore the $sin(x)$ term wouldn't the bound have to be $|x-2| < 1 + \epsilon$? or are you already assuming this when you gave your claim?

Comment: As $ϵ<ϵ+\sin^2(\frac{ϵ^2}9)$, the chain $|x-2|<ϵ<ϵ+\sin^2(\frac{ϵ^2}9)$ implies by the first assumption that $|f(x)-2|<ϵ$. And to appreciate the smallness of this reduction of usable $x$ values, use $|\sin x|=\sin|x|\le\min(1,|x|)$. However, the reduction itself needs a lower bound, not an upper bound.